# How to generate onset and offset cosine squared ramps in web audio API?

Tags: web-audio-api

web audio API creates following wave forms
-Sine Wave
-Square Wave 
-Sawtooth Wave
-Triangle wave

if someone wants to create cosine wave then how can create this wave?
How to generate onset and offset cosine squared ramps

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the only way to make a cosine wave is to use a PeriodicWave with an OscillatorNode.

To create a cosine-squared wave, there are at least 4 ways:

- Use a AudioBufferSource with the desired wave
- Use a WaveShaperNode to square a cosine wave
- Use a GainNode to multiply the cosine wave with itself
- Use the property that cos(x)^2 = (1+cos(2*x))/2

Comment: Thank you Raymond :) Now i can generate cosine squared . Can you please tell me more about onset and offset ramps?

Comment: You'll have to describe what you mean by onset and offset ramps. I don't know what you're looking for here.  Do you mean you want an oscillator to start at zero amplitude, increase to full amplitude and then fade to zero?

Comment: I have to do this "Generate three 200 ms same-frequency/same-intensity tones are repeated in succession with 200 ms silence between them and with 10 ms long cosine-squared ramps at all onsets and offsets". I am done with frequency, intensity, silence between them, I'm confused about 10ms long cosine-squared ramps at all onsets and offsets.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?  I still don't fully understand your question, but I'm guessing you want the want the oscillator amplitude to look like a cosine squared ramp, which seems really weird.  A sin(x)^2 wave makes more sense to me to ramp up and down.  Consider connecting your oscillator to a gain node which uses gain.gain.setValueCurveAtTime() to do the ramp up/down.  Set the curve to the curve you want at the times you want this to take effect.